# How to read pipe-separated string into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to read a file into `spark` (`databricks`) as `bytes`, and convert it to a string.

```
file_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

This is all fine, and I have my data, as a pipe delimited string, including carriage returns etc. It all looks good.  Something like:

```
"Column1"|"Column2"|"Column3"|"Column4"|"Column5"
"This"|"is"|"some"|"data."|
"Shorter"|"line."|||
```

I want this in a `dataframe` though so that I can manipulate it, and initially I was attempting to use the following:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("delimiter", '|')
  .load(???)
```

I appreciate that the `load()` portion is really meant to be a path to a location on the `filesystem` ... so have been struggling with that one.

I have therefore reverted to using `pandas` as it makes life a lot easier:

```
import io
import pandas

temp = io.StringIO(file_bytes.decode("utf-8"))
df = pandas.read_csv(temp, sep="|")
```

This is a `pandas` `dataframe`, and not a `spark` `dataframe`, which as far as I am aware (and it's a very loose awareness) has pros and cons relating to where it lives (in memory) which relates to scaleability/ cluster-usage etc.

Initially, is there a way for me to get my string into a `spark` `dataframe` using `sqlContext`? Maybe I am missing some parameter or switch etc., or should I just stick with `pandas`?

The main thing I am worried about is that right now files are quite small (200 kb or so), but they might not be forever, and I'd like to reuse a pattern that will allow me to work with larger things (which is why I am marginally concerned about using pandas).

Answer (score 4):

You can actually load an RDD of strings using the CSV reader.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader

So, assuming `lines` is an RDD of strings that you parsed as you described, you can run:

```
df = spark.read.csv(lines, sep='|', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

The CSV source will then scan the RDD instead of trying to load files. This lets you perform custom pre-processing prior to parsing.